# How to use the MySql 's methods DATE_ADD,DATE_FORMAT in Zend Framework2

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, dateadd

I have a sql query string to my database

I hope this mysql sql can find the database row create time plus one day less time now

```
sql ='SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE (DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(`create_date`, '%Y-%m-%e %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) <= now())
```

i know zf1 code

zf1

```
function test(){
   $select = $this->select(true)->setIntegrityCheck(false);
   $select->where("DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(`om_created`, '%Y-%m-%e %H:%i:%s'), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)  <= now()));
   $data = $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Comment: And what do you get.?

Comment: why You are trying to use DATE_ADD , DATE_FORMAT? What result You are expecting?

Comment: what's with the `+30` in your 2nd DATE_FORMAT? I have never seen code like that before

Comment: use `INTERVAL 1 DAY` if you want 1 day

Comment: @TinTran +30 the line is test code , I fix the original problem code

Comment: well now you edited your question, looks all good now

Comment: I had a little mistake '

It is the role of the

Comment: This is to order inquiry,Query over unpaid 1 day deadline -- @ripa

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE DATE_ADD(create_date, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) <= NOW()
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE DATE_ADD(create_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) <= NOW()
```

Comment: Thank you, this may be the role originally,I just had a little 'symbol

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like:

select * from table where `date` >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)

In ZF1 you can write something like:

```
$select->from('tablename')
 ->where( 'date >=  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 month)');
```